# Using Mobaxterm right-click paste, execute large blocks of pasted code one at a time?

Tags: mobaxterm

I've been using MobaXterm for a while now, and frequently use right-click paste to execute small blocks of code at the Linux command line or in a Python interpreter.  My intention is that each line should be executed one at a time, even if I paste several lines at once.  This used to work fine, but recently the application behavior changed and now I have to hit enter after each line.  I have checked and "Paste using right click" is checked in the terminal settings menu.  Does anyone know how to change this behavior?  TIA